# Why is Android picking wrong density images?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a Coordinator layout and a an `ImageView` for profile pic that is supposed to "hang" from the ActionBar. The problem is that Android is picking the wrong image from the different density drawable folders. Here is how the layout looks:

[image]

You can see here that the image is covering almost the entire screen(it isn't supposed to). Here are the various drawable dimensions I have provided in the respective folders:

- drawable-mdpi/avatar.png | 310x310px
- drawable-hdpi/avatar.png | 465x465px
- drawable-xhdpi/avatar.png | 621x621px
- drawable-xxhdpi/avatar.png | 931x931px

Now, why isn't Android showing the image like covering a small area(as it would do as per mdpi)?

(The above test screen is xxhdpi)

***Note:*** The image has been created in Photoshop Artboard where we assume that density of desktop is mdpi and scale up/down for other densities in mobile.

---

Code for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"/>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Open your XML in text mode (not design mode) and do `ctrl+0`, on top of the preview try changing the default device.

Comment: @Enzokie : I have tried changing various devices. It shows the same on all of them. I tested on a real device also with no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that the profile picture should be small? Your standard modern phone has somewhere around 360-400 horizontal dp; if your mdpi image is 310x310 (and the rest of your images scale accordingly), then I would expect the image to be nearly as wide as a normal phone.

Everything appears to be working correctly given the dimensions you've posted.

Comment: Consider this: A typical device is 720x1280 or 1080x1920px. Now, if the image is 300 something on mdpi, it would occupy less than half the screen width. Here, it is taking 80-90% of it.

Comment: A typical device is 720x1280 at xhdpi, meaning it is 360 dp across. Your xhdpi image is 621px wide; 621 is most of 720.

Comment: TY. Sometimes, these dp calculations get to you. This was one of those times. Never again...*hopefully*!